# Typescript - getter and setter: detect object change when call the getter

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following class:

```
@Injectable()
export class ViewCacheService{

    private key: string = "cache";
    private prefix: string = "view";

    private get viewFifoStack() {
        let _viewFifoStack: ViewCacheFifoStack = this._clientCacheService.getFromCache(this.key, this.prefix) as ViewCacheFifoStack;
        if(!_viewFifoStack) _viewFifoStack = new ViewCacheFifoStack();
        return _viewFifoStack;

    }

    private set viewFifoStack(viewFifoStack: ViewCacheFifoStack) {
        if(viewFifoStack)
            this._clientCacheService.setToCache(this.key, this.prefix, this.viewFifoStack);
    }

    constructor(private _clientCacheService: ClientCacheService) {}

    setFocusElement(element: HTMLElement) : void {
        let node: ViewCache = this.viewFifoStack.getNode(true);
        if(!node) node = new ViewCache();
        node.focusElement = element;
        this.viewFifoStack.addNode(node);
    }
}
```

This class as a property called `viewFifoStack` that has a setter and a getter. The problem is that, when I call the method `setFocusElement` and execute the `this.viewFifoStack.addNode(node)`, the setter function is not called.

I know the behavior is correct and should work like that. What I'm looking for is a way to call the setter any time the stack private property of `ViewFifoStack` suffers a change.

Follows the `ViewCacheFifoStack` and `ViewCache` class:

```
class ViewCacheFifoStack{
    private stack: Array<ViewCache> = new Array<ViewCache>();
    constructor() {}

    getNode(remove: boolean = true): ViewCache | null{
        if(remove) this.removeLast();
        if(this.stack.length > 0) 
            return this.stack[this.stack.length - 1];
        return null;
    }

    addNode(viewCache: ViewCache): void {
        if(viewCache)
            this.stack.push(viewCache);
    }

    private removeLast(): boolean{
        if(this.stack.length > 0){
            this.stack.pop();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class ViewCache {
    focusElement: Element;
}
```

Comment: Use `console.log(viewCache)` see what it pass you probably need something like `(if viewCache !== undefined)`.

Comment: Hi @Swoox. I changed the code. I had a mistake. But the problem that I'm exposing is not that